# Marker position not updating correctly (only when provider is google)

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I am using React Native Maps, which shows the selected location with a marker. When the user selects a new location, the marker is not updating to the new position. This only happens when the "provider is google". When I try using apple maps, the marker updates to the correct position.

below is my code

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import MapView, { Marker } from "react-native-maps";


const _renderMarker = (location) => {
  return location.map(({ lat, lng, index }) => {
    return (
      <Marker
        key={index}
        coordinate={{
          latitude: lat,
          longitude: lng,
        }}
      ></Marker>
    );
  });
};


const Map = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.searchboxcontainer}>
      <MapView
        style={styles.map}
        region={{
          latitude: props.mdata.lat,
          longitude: props.mdata.lng,
          latitudeDelta: props.mdata.latDelta, // 0.00822,
          longitudeDelta: props.mdata.lngDelta, // 0.04421,
        }}
       provider={"google"} //works when using apple maps
      >
        {_renderMarker([{ lat: props.mdata.lat, lng: props.mdata.lng }])}
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mapboxcontainer: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
  },
  map: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
  },
});

export default Map;
```